# Making custom navigation bar with left- and right-aligned elements

Tags: html, css

I did a lot of searching before asking this question and could not find a solution. Problem: I would like a simple navigation bar with one left-aligned item and the rest right-aligned.

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif
}

.nav {
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #7a7d82;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.nav li:first-child {
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-custom">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried using `float` but that does not seem to work. I want the navbar to be positioned fixed to the top of the screen. I have tried splitting the "HOME" and the rest of the menu items into separate `<ul>` tags but that does not seem to work either. I apologize if this has been asked before, but I am new to CSS and still learning the ropes.

Comment: so whats wrong with this? - as to me this does what you asked for

Comment: "I have tried using float but that does not seem to work." Care to elaborate?

Comment: http://codepen.io/onlyone_aos/full/dvGNBJ/ 

Here is the codepen. It does not seem to work. Someone found the solution below. I have marked it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `.nav` a flex-container (`display: flex`) and apply `margin-right: auto;` to its first child:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #7a7d82;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-custom">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you for the prompt reply. Can you elaborate on why this fixed it?

Comment: Actually, your float solution works here, on Firefox Mac, both the snippet above and the COdepen - it must be a browser issue that you don't see it working. Still, the flexbox approoach is quite useful and quick: You define the ul as a flexbox and apply margin: auto (left or right) to the element where you want the left/right seperation.

Answer (score 0):

Floating will do the trick, and there are a couple of ways to approach it:

This fiddle achieves it using classes:

https://jsfiddle.net/vbc330Lj/

```
<div class="navbar-custom">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="left"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

#navbar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
.nav li{
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav li.left{
  float: left;
 }
.nav li.right{
  float:right
 }
```

And you can also be more dynamic by only targeting the first item (if that's the real use-case):

https://jsfiddle.net/2bc4j3c7/

```
<div class="navbar-custom">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

#navbar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
.nav li{
 margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav li{
 float: right
}
.nav li:first-of-type{
 float: left;
}
```